# Upload a bundle to remote Karaf

Tags: jmx, karaf

i have a Karaf on the host A. How to upload a bundle into this host A from another host (B) ?

With JMX service, i can do that ?

Regards.

HNT,

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to me, that you may need [Karaf Cave](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/cave.html).
In short I can tell you, that Cave provides karaf cluster support. In your case host A could be the master and host B the slave, so when both karaf instances belong to the same cave cluster, when you install a bundle or feature the changes are propagated to other nodes in the same cluster.

I highly recommend you to have a look on Karaf cave documentation and all those ideas will become clear after that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want to deploy a bundle to a single Karaf instance? So use a file transfer protocol like SCP to upload the bundle to the file system of the target host. Then either move it to karaf's deploy folder or do a local maven install and install the bundle from  karaf shell afterwards. Instead you could use a remote maven repository like nexus.